# Dart, get all n number letter values from a list

Tags: list, dart

Let's say I have a list

```
List test = ['hello', 'two', 'mountain', 'day',  'tomorrow', 'bye', 'sad', 'yesterday'];

ExpectedResult = ['two', 'day', 'bye', 'sad'];
```

I want to extract all values from a list that are of certain number of characters long, in this case all result words that I'm looking have three characters, is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<String> nLetters(List<String> list, int n) {
    return list.where((word) => word.length == n).toList();
}
```

Calling `nLetters(['hello', 'two', 'mountain', 'day',  'tomorrow', 'bye', 'sad', 'yesterday'], 3)` will produce `[two, day, bye, sad]`